# How to use setTimeout and setInterval to display HTML content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to show the image for a few seconds and then hide it and show the rest HTML section.

Initially, I want to display the image for 2 seconds and hide the DIV till the time. After 2 seconds hide the image and display the div only.

What I tried using js

```js
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('Image').style.display = 'block', 2000);
setInterval(() => document.getElementById('Item').style.display = 'none', 2000);
```

```html
<div id="Image">
  <img src="../img-correct.png" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="item" id="Item">
  <h3>Time:</h3>
</div>
```

I am getting the div first then after 2 seconds I am getting an image.

Comment: so why are you doing the opposite with your code? after 2 seconds, you show the image and hide the html

Answer (score 1):

On `loading`, you need to show `image` and hide the `item`. And on `setTimeout` callback, hide the `image` and show the `item` as follows.

FYI, `setTimeout` callback is only called one time after the `timeout` but `setInterval` callback is called periodically based on the `time` mentioned on second param.

```js
document.getElementById('Image').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('Item').style.display = 'none';

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('Image').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Item').style.display = 'block';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="Image">
  <img src="../img-correct.png" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="item" id="Item">
  <h3>Time:</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This example is the one that worked for me to hide and show various load percentage Div's in the web preloader. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set image display to: 'block' and item display to: 'none' then change both after 2000ms.

```
const item = document.getElementById('Item');
item.style.display = 'none';

const image = document.getElementById('Image');
image.style.display = 'block';

setTimeout(() => {
  item.style.display = 'block';
  image.style.display = 'none';
}
 ,2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)'s toggle():

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(fn => setTimeout(fn, ms));

const toggle_content = () => {
  document.querySelector('#Image').classList.toggle("u-none");
  document.querySelector('#Item').classList.toggle("u-none");
};

wait(2000).then(toggle_content);
```

```css
/* Utility Classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Image"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100/0bf" alt="image"></div>
<div id="Item" class="u-none"><h3>HELLO</h3></div>
```

The best part of the above is that by setting initially an element class as `u-none` JS will not cause flicks of content.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle a variable as the boolean state of what component will be displayed right now. Then in `setInterval`, using the variable, display the element you want each call. Like this:

```js
var imageShow=true;

document.getElementById('Item').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('Image').style.display = 'block';

setInterval(() => {
document.getElementById('Image').style.display = imageShow?'none':'block';
document.getElementById('Item').style.display = imageShow?'block':'none';
imageShow=!imageShow;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="Image">
  <img src="../img-correct.png" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="item" id="Item">
  <h3>Time:</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="../img-correct.png" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="item" id="item">
</div>
```

```js
// setTimeout allows us to run a function once after the interval of time.
// setInterval allows us to run a function repeatedly, starting after the interval of time, then repeating continuously at that interval.

// displayed and removed after 2seconds
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none', 2000);

// Waiting 2 seconds to add text to your div with id of "item" (happening once => setTimeout)
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = "time:", 2000);
```

Codepen => https://codepen.io/zibobilo/pen/WNxvqPL